# Why is my code given a valueerror in kattis in R2?

Tags: python

I am trying to solve the problem called [R2](https://open.kattis.com/problems/r2) on kattis but for some reason, while the program (written in python) runs in the IDLE, I am met with a run time error in kattis with the judgement being a valueerror.

Here's my code:

```
R1 = int(input('input R1 '))
S = int(input('input S '))

R2 = (S*2)-R1
print(R2)
```

Comment: Does it say which line the error is on? have you tried print(int(R2)) ?

Comment: it doesn't say the which line it is on...

Comment: I tried that : still a run time error

Answer (score 1):

```
nums = input().split(' ')
r2 = 2*int(nums[1]) - int(nums[0])
print(r2)
```

The problem states that the two numbers will be input on a single line. You are attempting to capture two numbers input on two separate lines by calling `input` twice.

Answer (score 0):

Darrahts pointed one problem out.

The 2nd Problem is:  `input([prompt])` writes the prompt to the standard output,
however you should only write your solution to standard output.